# How to modify my app/game so that it can load quickly?

Tags: android, android-studio, surfaceview, runnable, 2d-games

I have created a simple game using a class a which **extends** **SurfaceView** and **implements Runnable**. In the game the drawing is done inside the **public void run**. Which is targeted by a thread as soon as the activity launches. The game is taking a lot of time(sometimes 10-15 sec) to load. As well as when the game is paused(**thread. join()**) and resumed(**thread = new Thread(this); thread.start()**) it takes too much time.
What might be making the game load slow? And what can be the solutions?

Comment: 10-15 seconds is an eternity. You need to profile your app (perhaps with `traceview`) and figure out where the time is being spent.

Comment: @fadden Is **traceview** a replacement to the surface view?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the game was loading slow because the thread has been running continuously, without any **sleep**. So just adding `Thread.sleep(15);` inside the **run**, with all exceptions handled, solved this problem. Thank you for supporting.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause is resource loading.

I/O operations are very slow, so, if you try and load all your bitmaps before actually drawing, this can cause significant delay before the drawing actually starts.

One strategy to avoid this is to preload your assets before you actually need to start using them. A lot of games do this in the so - called Splash screen. Also, don't be too fast to recycle your assets and free the memory they are using. This means that you will need to reload them the next time you start.

Overall, there is no exact recipe of how to do it - there is a constant trade - off between load times and memory consumption. You just need to experiment and try to see what fits your use case best.

Be sure to profile your app, examine the object creations and memory allocation calls using your IDE. Most of the time you can easily pinpoint the causes of problems there.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am shall apply this strategy and check if it helps. Thank you once again.